# caliburn micro: MVVM parent view and child view of parent need to deactivate child

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I need some help with reaching my TicketViewModel with Caliburn micro using ContentControl. I want to reach the ticketView(Model) using a button in StartView. (and deactivating startView)

*next picture are the interactions i want to have with their CM implementations*
https://i.stack.imgur.com/igfWj.jpg

*this is the app thus far*
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnIPu.jpg

The header and styleElements are of the ShellView. The center square is a contentcontrol. with default the startview in activated.

As you can see, I want to reach TicketsView using a button in startView(that itself is nested in a contentControl in ShellView), and using a a MenuItem in ShellView.

*Code in Shellview*
`<ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ActiveItem"/>`

*Code in ShellViewModel*

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>
{
public ShellViewModel(){
ActivateItem(new StartViewModel());}

public void AlleTicketsPageLaden(){
ActivateItem(new AlleTicketsViewModel());}
```

*Code in StartView*  `<Button Content="Tickets" x:Name="StartTicketKnop"/>`

*Code In StartViewModel*

```
  public class StartViewModel : Conductor<object>
  {
    public void StartTicketKnop()
    {
      ActivateItem(new AlleTicketsViewModel());
    }
```

Comment: Either keep a reference to that `public AlleTicketsViewModel AlleTicketsVM {get;set;} = new AlleTicketsViewModel()` or write some kind of service that handles changing items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

Create class `ActivateWindow` like this:

```
 public static class ActivateWindow
    {
        public static ShellViewModel Parent;

        public static void OpenItem(IScreen t)
        {
            Parent.ActivateItem(t);
        }
    }
```

And in your `ShellViewModel` constructor

```
public ShellViewModel()
        {
            ActivateWindow.Parent = this;
        }
```

Now in any `ViewModel` you can do the folowing:

```
ActivateWindow.OpenItem(new YourViewModel());
```

Comment: I have tried doing this but my OpenItem doesn't call the View's constructor. I don't know what I am missing